# Can multiple controllers access the same database at the same time using different dbcontexts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using entity framework and a controller with async methods.

While one controller is playing with the database via an async method , the server might receive a request from another client to play with the same database.

I understand that dbcontext is not thread safe.

Why is there not a problem here?

Comment: It depends on the type of database you are connected to.  Some have locks to prevent contention when multiple users access the database at the same time.  SQL Server have locks but the Jet Engine or ACE driver (used by access and excel) do not have locks to prevent contention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that dbcontext is not thread safe.

That means that the same `DbContext` *instance* should not be used from multiple threads.  It's perfectly fine for multiple `DbContext`s to hit a database on different threads.

What happens in the *database* in that situation depends on the databases's locking/concurrency settings, but that's another question.